# quiz game unity-problem with button while i try to get answer input from the user, no results have been obtained

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an simple quiz game, and below is my source code. I'm unable to get user input for the question. So I have added home and back button to the scene. Now that's also not working. Please take a look.

```c#
public class Level2UI: MonoBehaviour {
  private List < string > sceneHistory = new List < string > ();
  [SerializeField] private Level2Manager gameManager;
  [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI questionText;
  [SerializeField] private List < Button > options;
  [SerializeField] private Color CorrColor,
  WrongColor,
  NormalColor;
  private Question question;
  private bool answered;
  // Start is called before the first frame update        
  void setButton() {
    for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++) {
      Button localBtn = options[i];
      localBtn.onClick.AddListener(delegate {
        ClickedAnswer(localBtn);
      });
      Debug.Log("testclick");
    }
  }
  public void SetQuestion(Question question) {
    this.question = question;
    questionText.text = question.questionInfo;

    List < string > answerList = ShuffleList.ShuffleListItems < string > (question.options);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.Count; i++) {
      options[i].GetComponentInChildren < TextMeshProUGUI > ().text = answerList[i];
      Debug.Log("check");
      options[i].name = answerList[i];
      options[i].image.color = NormalColor;
    }
    answered = false;
    setButton();
  }

  public void ClickedAnswer(Button btn) {
    print("txt");
    if (!answered) {
      answered = true;
      bool val = gameManager.Answer(btn.name);
      if (val) {
        btn.image.color = CorrColor;
        Debug.Log("test1");
      }
      else {
        btn.image.color = WrongColor;
        Debug.Log("test");
      }
    }
  }
  public void LoadScene(string newScene) {
    sceneHistory.Add(newScene);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(newScene);
  }
  public bool PreviousScene() {
    bool returnValue = false;
    if (sceneHistory.Count >= 2) {
      returnValue = true;
      sceneHistory.RemoveAt(sceneHistory.Count - 1);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please add the code as Text and format it with the {} Button instead of adding images.

Answer (score 1):

Did you assign the button? You need to assign the button or initialize it. Then put listener to it in the code or attach the method directly to the gameObject itself in the editor.

To assign a button

```
Button btn = transform.Find("btn").getComponent<Button>();
btn.onClick.AddListener(()=>{
// perform your action
});
```

I hope I helped a little? If not, I'm sorry.

Comment: options[i].GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { ClickedAnswer(localBtn); }); but not able to detech touch

Comment: Oh okay, did you check the raycast target of the button? Also, if there's textmesh above your button check the raycast target. Something like this happened to me before

Comment: it is not working, as i am working in canvas onClick.add listener() is mostly used

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually the mistake was not with the script, event system was missing

Comment: Glad you found the problem.